# error while applying plugin 'com.google.gms.google-services', version: '5.0.0'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-studio, build.gradle

I am trying to create an app for my college project but getting gradle exception

**android\build.gradle code:**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.6'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:5.0.0'  // Google Services plugin
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.9'
    }
}
plugins{
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '5.0.0'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**app\build.gradle code**

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"
}
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}
def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}
def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}
def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  // Google Services plugin
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.flutterflow.sofinder"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}
flutter {
    source '../..'
}
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.2')
}
```

**and the error is:**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'E:\App Development\sofinderapp\android\build.gradle' line: 17

* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'com.google.gms.google-services', version: '5.0.0'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.google.gms.google-services:com.google.gms.google-services.gradle.plugin:5.0.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1</sub>
```

Please help me resolve the error and also I had not used any gradle command if it is needed please do tell me